# Bash history for root?

Tags: bash, history

After installing 'ubuntu-desktop' on 12.04-LTS-server, the arrow keys work correctly
for history navigation when the user is not root. However, for the root user, the
arrow keys (for example, the up-arrow) do not work when using a shell with the
Gnome desktop.

If the root user is connected via ssh, the arrow keys work.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is a result of no configuration of the shell during startup.

Try running a new shell with the command `bash -ls`

This will give you a login shell as when logging in with SSH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it does not solve the problem.